# callablestatment output generates Invalid column index using struts2

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I'm tyring to see how many users I inserted into my oracle 11g database using the following code (cannot look at the table right now, so I'm doing this).  Anyone knows why I'm getting a Invalid Column Index from this.  Stack Trace is after the code:

```
  String storedFunc = "{call :1 := call ENTITY.TABLE_NAME.getUserCount()}";
  CallableStatement cstmt2 = conn.prepareCall(storedFunc);
  // register the output parameter
  cstmt2.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);              
  Integer count = (Integer) cstmt2.getInt(1);   //line 68
  cstmt2.execute();              
  cstmt2.close();
```

and the stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getInt(OracleCallableStatement.java:1476)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getInt(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:783)    at com.company.tool.server.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:68)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)  at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)     at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong call-escape syntax.

The correct syntax would be:

```
String storedFunc = "{? = call ENTITY.TABLE_NAME.getUserCount()}";
```

See also: [Function Call Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxref.htm#autoId10)